# Test that associated model exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

A user has one profile. The profile was created after creating the user.  How can I test that the profile exists using rspec?

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:student) }
subject { user }
it { is_expected.to be_valid }
it { is_expected.to (#profile exist))   # I don't know what goes here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't write it in one line. Here is my thought -

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:student) }
subject { user }
it { is_expected.to be_valid }
expect(user.profile).to be_present
```